# use awk to confront first number in every line of a file and print the whole line that contains the largest one

Tags: linux, awk, ubuntu-12.04

The file I have looks like this: (thanks to @fredtantini)

```
 37.36      44.22    -221.12       0.85       2.02       4.00       0.49   2345.147  '/home/~/gold_soln_x_m1_70.sdf'                     'X'    
 38.46      45.89    -229.45       1.49       1.94       4.00       0.61   2370.912  '/home/~/gold_soln_y_m1_69.sdf'                     'Y'    
 39.90      46.86    -234.28       0.29       2.66       4.00       1.00   2368.052  '/home/~/gold_soln_w.sdf'                     'W'    
 37.75      48.10    -240.50       2.58       3.77       4.00       0.60   2220.947  '/home/~/gold_soln_z.sdf'                     'Z'
```

I need to have as output:

```
 39.90      46.86    -234.28       0.29       2.66       4.00       1.00   2368.052  '/home/~/gold_soln_w.sdf'                     'W'
```

printed in another file but I've never used awk so I have no idea on how to organize my script. looking for answers I found this:

```
awk'
function max(x){i=0;for(val in x){if(i<=x[val]){i=x[val];}}return i;}
{a[$2]=$2;next}`
END{minimum=min(a);maximum=max(a);print "Maximum = "maximum "}'
```

but it's not working and i have no idea why.

## I've tried @fredtantini answer and it works from terminal but i need to insert it in a script:

The complete script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/~/
        for k in $( cat lista_sottocartelle ); do
            cd /home/~/$k 
            awk 'BEGIN{max=0}{if($1>max){max=$1;maxline=$0}}END{print maxline}' bestranking.lst >> indirizzi_ASP.lst
```

The output is: **syntax error: unexpected end of file**

## **Edit**

I just forgot to add done at the end of the script.
thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
~$ awk 'BEGIN{max=0}{if($1>max){max=$1;maxline=$0}}END{print maxline}' f
 39.90      46.86    -234.28       0.29       2.66       4.00       1.00   2368.052  '/home/~/gold_soln_w.sdf'                     'W'
```

For each line, you check if first number is greater than current max. If it is, you save the line in `maxline`. At the end, you print this line.

A shorter version doing the same thing (thanks to @Jotne):

```
awk '$1>max {max=$1;maxline=$0}END{print maxline}'
```

There are several problems in your script (`$2` is the second column, min function is not defined…)

Comment: You do not need to set a variable to `0` and this can be shorten some to some like this:         `awk '$1>max {max=$1;maxline=$0}END{print maxline}'`

Comment: @Jotne Indeed, but alikino is unfamiliar with awk and this seems more readable to me. For completness, I will add this to my answer if you allow me.

Comment: It works fine from terminal but when I use it in a script it says:  syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: This will fail if `$1` is always less than or equal to zero. You need to use `awk '(NR==1)||($1>max){max=$1;maxline=$0}END{print maxline}'` instead and what is the desired output if 2 lines have the same `$1` value - the first occurrence or the last or something else?